# $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left(\frac{1}{1+|x|^2}\right)^{s}dx$ converges if and only if $s$ holds...

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

Some time ago I saw in a book (which unfortunately I don't remember which one it was) that the integral 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left(\frac{1}{1+|x|^2}\right)^{s}dx$$ (I don't know if it was that integral or this one $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left(\frac{1}{|x|^2}\right)^{s}dx$, I don't remember it well)

converges if and only if the exponent $s$ holds a certain condition (which is determined by the dimension of the space)

Does anyone know what values of $s$ the integral converges to?
Does anyone know a book that shows this result? Well, I'm looking for the books (among them Stein, Barry Simon, Rudin, etc.) that I could have seen and I still can't find it ...

Answer (score 5):

The integral $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\dfrac{1}{(1+|x|^{2})^{s}}dx$ converges if and only if $2s>n$, one may look at $\displaystyle\int_{|x|>1}\dfrac{1}{|x|^{2s}}dx$ and switching to spherical integral.

The integral $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\dfrac{1}{|x|^{2s}}dx$ diverges no matter what. For the convergence of $\displaystyle\int_{|x|<1}\dfrac{1}{|x|^{2s}}dx$ one requires $2s<n$. For the convergence of $\displaystyle\int_{|x|>1}\dfrac{1}{|x|^{2s}}dx$ one requires $2s>n$, these two conditions cannot be simultaneously met.

Answer (score 2):

The surface area of the sphere with radius $\rho$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}\rho^{n-1}$, hence

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{d\mu}{(1+\|x\|^2)^s}=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\rho^{n-1}}{(1+\rho^2)^s}\,d\rho $$
is convergent as soon as $n-1-2s<-1$, i.e. $s>\frac{n}{2}$. In such a case the above integral equals
$$ \pi^{n/2}\frac{\Gamma\left(s-\frac{n}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(s)}. $$